# Configuring .ASP pages in IIS 7.5 in Windows server 2003

Tags: asp-classic, iis-7.5

I am trying to add a virtual directory in IIS 7.5 version of Windows server 2003. But i could not browse my default.asp page. How can i troubleshoot this issue ?

Comment: The browser shows 500 internal error

Comment: There is no IIS7.5 on Windows 2003, do you mean IIS7.5 express?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you installed IIS Express7.5... correct? If that is the case, take a look at failed request trace log files located in "%userprofile%\My Documents\IISExpress\TraceLogFiles\" and also see if there are any interesting events in event viewer.